# How can I re-open the gdpr consent window in android?

Tags: android, gdprconsentform

I'm trying to continuously pop up a consent window for users who have not consented to GDPR on Android.
How can I bring up the consent window again?
You can use the reset() method, but the official documentation says not to use it in production versions.
What can I do?

Comment: Can you please share some code that you invoke for asking the user for consent?

Comment: what GDPR framework are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user had not consented, then you're supposed to use non-personalized ads. That's it.

The whole point of GDPR law is to let users opt-out of personalized ads. IANAL, but I'm pretty sure that requiring users to consent is illegal. If some kind of tracking is absolutely essential to the service you provide, then the consent is implied and cannot be revoked, so that's not a technical problem either.

You need a legal help, not technical.